# local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment error

Tags: django, python-2.7

Now I've read all the posts on SO regarding this error, and I can conclude that my error is quite a different case.

The error: 
`Local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment
[21/Jun/2018 09:05:58] "POST /details/create/ HTTP/1.1" 400 54`

Now here's the code where I initialize `instance`:

```
def create(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    try:
        params = post_data(request)

        try:
            instance = Sales_detail.objects.get(id = params.get("id",None))
            params["item"] = instance.item.pk
            params["price"] = instance.price.pk
            params["sales"] = instance.sales.pk
            detail_form = Detail_form(params, instance = instance)
        except Sales_detail.DoesNotExist:
            params["item"] = instance.item.pk
            params["price"] = instance.price.pk
            params["sales"] = instance.sales.pk
            detail_form = Detail_form(params)

        if detail_form.is_valid():
            detail_form.save()
        else:
            raise_error(detail_form.errors,True)

        return success("Details successfully saved.")
    except Exception as e:
        return error(e)
else:
    return redirect("dashboard")
```

I have no idea what I'm missing, clearly `instance` is initialized before doing anything with it.

Comment: `instance` is not initialized in the exception handler.

Comment: Reference instance outside of the try block, or reference it again when the except is caught

Comment: @StephenRauch noted. I'll try that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error occurs when this line

```
instance = Sales_detail.objects.get(id = params.get("id",None))
```

is executed. The code isn't enecuted completely. So the instance hasn't been definited. And then the code goes to

```
params["item"] = instance.item.pk
```

Since the `instance` hasn't been definited, the Error

```
The error:  Local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment
```

occurs.